# Unity iOS build problem archive build success but simulator run failed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

there is a problem that I haven't been able to solve since yesterday. I get an ios build from Unity and then run it with xcode. When I follow the path xcode -> product -> archive and get build, I can get it and publish it without any problems, but when I want to try it on the simulator, UnityFramework gives a lot of errors. How can I solve this problem?

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR2DY.png)

Comment: Did you change the SDK version in the Unity iOS player settings to Simulator SDK?

Comment: No :) i will change and try it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

"Did you change the SDK version in the Unity iOS player settings to Simulator SDK?"

I change the sdk "Device" to "Simulator" fixed.